# How do i fix my sub navigation bar when my page is zoomed in or out?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, uinavigationbar, navbar

so im having issues with my sub nav bar on my site 
when a user zooms in or out the items in the sub nav bar adjust and the last item goes to a different line. how do i control that?

i dont want the sub nav bar to adjust when the user zooms in or out

please help

below you find my code for my sub nav bar

```
enter code here <div id="subnav" class="subnav-stores">
        <ul class="clearfix">

     <li style="font-size: 14px; padding-right:8px; text-align: center;"><a                        href="/stores/speedway" class="">Speedway</a></li>
<li style="font-size: 14px; padding-right:8px; text-align: center;"><a href="/stores/ina"           class="" >Ina</a></li>
<li style="font-size: 14px; padding-right:8px; text-align: center;"><a href="/stores/grant" class="">Grant</a></li>
<li style="font-size: 14px; padding-right:8px; text-align: center;"><a href="/stores/phoenix" class="">Phoenix</a></li>
<li style="font-size: 14px; padding-right:8px; text-align: center;"><a href="/stores/mesa" class="">Mesa</a></li>
<li style="font-size: 14px; padding-right:8px; text-align: center;"><a  href="/stores/flagstaff" class="">Flagstaff</a></li>
<li style="font-size: 14px; padding-right:0px; text-align: center;"><a href="/stores/bookmans-sports-exchange" class="">Sports Exchange</a></li>
```

now i will show you the css for styling the css sub nav bar

```
      #subnav ul {
margin:1.6em 0;
list-style:none;
border:1px solid #d2cfc4;
border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
/*border-collapse: separate;*/ 
background-color: rgba(212, 209, 197, 0.3);
behavior:url(http://preview.drawbackwards.com/PIE.php);
position:relative;
z-index:0;
}
    #subnav li {float:left;
/*padding:8px;*/
border-right:1px solid #d2cfc4;
/*min-width:118px;*/
text-align:center;
font-size:14px;
padding:0 4px;
}
   .subnav-about li a {
    padding:4px 28px 5px 27px;
}
   .subnav-stores li a {
    padding:4px 33px 5px 33px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange things happen to a lot of CSS when the user zooms in or out, and if I'm honest I don't protect much against it.

However, if you did want to look into it I'd say hello to your new best friend, box-sizing: border-box.  this accounts for the border width in the overall width of the element.  I've also made your li elements percentage widths so they scale as the page moves and I got rid of all the horizontal padding on the `.subnav-stores li a`

```
 #subnav li {

     float:left;
     width:13%;
     border-right:1px solid #d2cfc4;
     text-align:center;
     font-size:14px;
     padding:4px 0;

     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
             box-sizing: border-box;

 }
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/pN24G/

Comment: that makes the width wider and moves the text over to the left so the end is longer . i want to keep the same width and everything just dont want the sub nav bar to adjust when zooming

Answer (score 0):

When you are building your bar use percentages in your css cos then when you are zoomed out it will be a percentage of the zoomed out page

Comment: when i use percentages it adjust my whole sub nav bar dimensions